# mock configuration in Grails tests

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, mocking

Prior to Grails 2.0.X it was possible to mock configuration using a `mockConfig` method provided by the base class that tests extend. However, in Grails 2.0.X it is recommended that test classes use the `@TestFor` mixin instead of extending a base class.

This mixin doesn't seem to provide anything equivalent to the `mockConfig` methods, so I can't figure out how to mock values in `Config.groovy`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have access to grailsApplication.config so you can modify these values as much as you need, so you can do

```
grailsApplication.config.some.config.setting = 'foo'
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm doing it this way (in the case when I'm testing a service):

```
service.grailsApplication.config.mysetting = 'my value'
def result = service.myMethod()
// check results
```

No other mocking required.

Comment: In this way (using `service.grailsApplication` rather than just `grailsApplication` as suggested in the accepted answer), you also avoid leaking the config to other tests which may make them flaky, so +1, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that there's a `config` object already in scope in the new Grails 2.x tests. So it's sufficient to say

```
config.some.config.setting = 'foo'
```

which will then be accessible from the `@TestFor` object under test.

If you need to create the object manually, then there's also a `grailsApplication` object in scope in the tests - to which the `config` object belongs. So this should work -

```
config.some.config.setting = 'foo'
def myService = new MyService(grailsApplication:grailsApplication)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like mockConfig() doesn't exist anymore in Grails 2.x. how about this:

```
    def mockConfig = new ConfigObject()
    mockConfig.some.config.setting = "foo"

    def myService = new MyService()
    myService.grailsApplication = [config: mockConfig]
```